# Extract only the server names from the below JSON whose status is online. Using jq version 1.5

Tags: json, unix, select, jq

I need to extract only the servers whose status is online (in this case server2, server 4) from the below json. Can anyone help me with this? I need solution in jq with 1.5 version

```json
[
    {
        "name": "core.vm",
        "machines": [{
                "name": "server1",
                "max_load": 220,
                "status": "offline"
            },
            {
                "name": "server2",
                "max_load": 220,
                "status": "online"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "cust.vm",
        "machines": [{
                "name": "server1",
                "max_load": 20,
                "status": "offline"
            },
            {
                "name": "server2",
                "max_load": 20,
                "status": "online"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "intl.vm",
        "machines": [{
                "name": "server3",
                "max_load": 20,
                "status": "offline"
            },
            {
                "name": "server4",
                "max_load": 20,
                "status": "online"
            }
        ]


    }
]
```

Comment: You said you wanted `server2` and `server 4` for output (though you presumably meant `server2` and `server4`), but there are two `server2` that are online, and you didn't explain how you chose to return `server2`. Is it because *all* instances of it are `online`, or is it because *any* instance of it is `online`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you wanted `server2` and `server 4` for output (though you presumably meant `server2` and `server4`), but there are two `server2` that are online, and you didn't explain how you chose to return `server2`.

---

If you want to include servers if *any* instance of it is online,

```sh
jq -r '[ .[].machines[] | select(.status == "online") | .name ] | unique[]'
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/Z3X2kUYk1K)

---

If you want to include servers if *all* instance of it are online, that would require something more complex.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Yes i need unique values only. The above code solves my problem